# CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class while using NSCoding

Tags: core-data, restkit, nscoding

I keep getting this error when run my app: "CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class "Ambulance"". I've seen this problem on stack overflow already but im unsure of how to implement a solution in my case. Any ideas?

Ambulance.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Ambulance : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ambulanceID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * distance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * etaDistance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * emsID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lng;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * occupancy;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * websocketServer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * seconds;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id eta;

+(Ambulance *)nearestAmbulanceByType:(NSString *)type;


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;


@end
```

Ambulance.m

```
#import "Ambulance.h"


@implementation Ambulance

@synthesize ambulanceID;
@synthesize distance;
@synthesize etaDistance;
@synthesize emsID;
@synthesize lat;
@synthesize lng;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize occupancy;
@synthesize type;
@synthesize websocketServer;
@synthesize seconds;
@synthesize eta;


+(Ambulance *)nearestAmbulanceByType:(NSString *)type {
NSArray *sortedArray = [Ambulance findByAttribute:@"type" withValue:type         andOrderBy:@"distance" ascending:YES];
return [sortedArray first];
 }


  - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
//Encode properties, other class variables, etc
[encoder encodeObject:self.ambulanceID forKey:@"ambulanceID"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.distance forKey:@"distance"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.etaDistance forKey:@"etaDistance"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.emsID forKey:@"emsID"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.lat forKey:@"lat"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.lng forKey:@"lng"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.occupancy forKey:@"occupancy"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.type forKey:@"type"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.websocketServer:@"websocketServer"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.seconds forKey:@"seconds"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.eta forKey:@"eta"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {


if((self = [super init])) {
    //decode properties, other class vars


    self.ambulanceID = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ambulanceID"];
    self.distance = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"distance"];
    self.etaDistance = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"etaDistance"];
    self.emsID = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"emsID"];
    self.lat = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"lat"];
    self.lng = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"lng"];
    self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    self.occupancy = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"occupancy"];
    self.type = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"type"];
    self.websocketServer = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"websocketServer"];
    self.seconds = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"seconds"];
    self.eta = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"eta"];

}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use any other initializer than `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` for your `NSManagedObject` subclass.

From the docs:

> Important:  This method is the designated initializer for
>   NSManagedObject. You must not initialize a managed object simply by
>   sending it init.

Are you sure you have to use NSCoding with your subclass? It would probably be sufficient to store the objectID since your object exists in a NSManagedObjectContext and probably gets persisted anyways.

If you really rely on NSCoding you have to determine and feed the proper NSManagedObjectContext to `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` in `initWithCoder:`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this has to do with RestKit and why you think you need to support coding.

Assuming you are using RestKit though, you should be able to change to:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ambulance" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    if((self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc])) {
    ...
```

If you aren't using RestKit then you'll need a different way to get the MOC.